simple relay/zener based switching power supply
Is this a reasonable way to build a switching supply without using power transistors or other modern devices? One concern is that this might oscillate a lot.  What might it be missing?
Here Vin > Vz; e.g. Vin might be ~12V and Vz might be 4V.


That relay won't live long.

@Hearth It needs separate turn-on and turn-off voltages instead of one.

A relay is rated to last for roughly 100000 operations. Let's be generous and say you've got an expensive relay that can survive 1 million operations. Let's say you're switching at a rate of 100Hz. That means you're switching 8.64 million times per day. Since the relay can only survive 1 million switches, that means it will only last roughly 2 hours 45 minutes.

Why would anyone want to actively drain the output capacitor through a resistor to ground? That's not done by any of the SMPS topologies I've ever seen.

@TooTea I think if one adds some resistance at Vin and a load Resistance Rl, an alternate design with the relay NO unconnected is essentially the same since C will discharge towards ground through a load resistance Rl, not shown.  I considered specifying that C is "very large" such that the charge and discharge time constants are large compared to relay switching time -- but that alone doesn't seem to solve the problems.  If charging C switched on at say 3.8V and switched off at 4.2V that would be closer to the intention.  I did ask 'what might be missing?'

You are creating a type of - I am being serious here - vibrator. For fairly obvious reasons, they are now considered obsolete.

I'm trying to remember how the old magnetic regulators for car alternators used to work. But of course, those are controlling the field current, not the load.

Indeed obsolete, but the existence proves that it was a reasonable and feasible way to implement SMPS before power transistors.

You are trying to discover the buck converter. People have been building those for several decades now.
Principle
Make a square wave voltage and average it using a low pass filter. The output voltage is the duty cycle times the input voltage.
Problem with using a relay
A relay takes several tens of milliseconds to turn on and off. I wouldn't expect a regular relay to switch faster than 100 Hz. For the few hours before the contacts wear out, the voltage regulation and load regulation will be terrible by today's standards. You circuit also shorts the voltage source with the output capacitor and the output when the relay is on. Anything connected on the output will get the full 12 V when the relay is on. A slightly better circuit would be to have an inductor (like in a buck converter) or at least a resistor (like a first order low pass filter) with the capacitor.
State of the art
Buck converters regularly operate at in MHz frequencies these days. They can have very fast and robust feedback controls (voltage comes back to correct value in less than a microsecond of a disturbance). A modern buck converter chip would cost less than a relay for a similar voltage and current ratings.
Potential use case of a self oscillating relay based buck converter
Someone is stranded on an island with a 12 battery, a loud 5 V motor siren, a large capacitor and electronics repair equipment. The siren is known to burn up if it is ran at a sustained 12 V. There is a shipping route nearby and someone on the ships might hear the siren.
Note of appreciation
Great way of thinking!! It might not work as a good voltage regulated power supply but it's definitely an excellent thought experiment. When I was learning electronics, I could think of ways to make astable, monostable or bistable multivibrators using a relay. And I guess those are some of the building blocks of a digital computer, so people who invented the first digital computers using relays might have been thinking along similar lines too.


Is this a reasonable way to build a switching supply without using power transistors or other modern devices?

No.

One concern is that this might oscillate a lot. What might it be missing?

The fact that its purpose was to provide some fixed voltage (or current?). I'm not sure why there's a Zener diode in there, but if you were hoping that would define the output voltage, you'd be mistaken.
There's rich theory and many introductions to switch-mode power supplies – maybe check for these.
Practically, "reasonable" would be "somewhat appropriate for a purpose and not overly complicated or expensive". So here's the thing: a switch-mode supply controller IC is not expensive nor hard to buy or use. It would switch at a high speed, making your inductor smaller and hence cheaper. My guess is that you'll be cheaper off buying a switch-mode IC, and using that.
As for learning, when you buy an old one that doesn't integrate the load switch, you can still probe all the signals with a multi-channel probe, and see exactly when its internal comperator switches the external transistor and so on.


Maybe use vacuum tubes?
If you look at the voltage regulators used in, say, automobiles from the 1950s, they were designed similarly to yours.  You can probably order one of those if you don't want to build one yourself.

